# How to generate ds:X509Certificate value from .p12 in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xml, openssl, digital-signature, xml-signature

I've a private key file **.p12**.
I'm using **Objective-C**.


I need to generate **Signed digital signature XML** like this:
[image]

The problem is, I cannot find out how to generate the value in **`<ds:X509Certificate>`**. I know it is a public key base64 encoded. But, I can't get the same string after testing various  encoding methods.. 
Need your help!

Comment: A X509 certificate is a public key + all the other parts that go into a certificate. Are you using a cert in the X509 certificate or something else?

Comment: @pd40 all I have is .p12; I've succeeded extracting from it cert and key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself. It is so easy.
Using Apple's **security.framework**:

```
NSString* pfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rsa_user" ofType:@"p12" ];

// Load Certificate
NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pfile];
CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;

SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
SecTrustRef myTrust;
extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);

SecCertificateRef myCertificate;
SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);
NSData *certificateData = (__bridge NSData *) SecCertificateCopyData(myCertificate);

// Output certificate base64 value. (This value goes to <ds:X509Certificate> tag )
NSLog(@"%@", [certificateData base64EncodedString]);

// Helper function

OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust)
{
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };

    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
        *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
    }

    if (options) {
        CFRelease(options);
    }

    return securityError;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post here all the steps to generate digital signature for xml?

Comment: @Christian I used private library to do this. There is specific cryptoproviders implemented. So I think it depends on what you need exactly. I saw a lot of example implemented and shared in SO, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me what library do you use?

Comment: @Christian it's a local government made library, we got it via sending an official email request. I think the standard implementations should work as well.